# Guardar el dato "1" desde un checkbox a una base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Necesito hacer una lista de tareas, y lo primero que necesito es que cuando una tarea esta checkeada, se guarde "1" en la base de datos, caso contrario, "0".
¿Alguno sabe como hacer esto?

Aqui unas imágenes de la idea (esta es la parte que me interesa):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la pagina completa, solo puse el código de la parte necesaria y que necesito, sino seria muy largo y no tendría sentido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la base de datos (son datos booleanos):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <!--Metadatos-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!--Titulo-->
<title>Playroom Main Page</title>
<!--Links-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
    <ul>
       <li>Del colegio:
         <form action="tempo.php" method="POST">
           <label>Lengua</label><input type="checkbox" name="iL"><br>
            <label>Matematica</label><input type="checkbox" name="iM"><br>
            <label>Ciencias naturales</label><input type="checkbox" name="iCN"><br>
             <label>Ciencias sociales</label><input type="checkbox" name="iCS"><br>
            <label>Ingles</label><input type="checkbox" name="ii"><br>
                                <input type="submit">
                            </form>
                        </li>
                      
 </body>
 </html>
```

tempo.php:

```
<?php
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
 $iL = $_POST["iL"]; 
 $iM = $_POST["iM"];
 $iCS = $_POST["iCS"];
 $iCN= $_POST["iCN"];
 $ii = $_POST["ii"];

 $m="INSERT INTO `checkboxes`(`lengua`, `csociales`, `matematica`, `cnaturales`,
 `ingles`) VALUES ('$iL','$iCS','$iM','$iCN','$ii')";

 if($iL==ON){
   $iL=TRUE;
   $b="INSERT INTO `checkboxes`(`lengua`) VALUES ('$iL')";
  }

  mysqli_query($conexion,$m);
  mysqli_query($conexion,$b);
   echo mysqli_error($conexion);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de las consideraciones con campos tipo checkbox, es que si el mismo no está seleccionado, ese valor no se envía, por lo que la variable `$_POST['el_campo']` **no existirá**. Hay varias formas de resolver esto.

Para no alterar mucho tu desarrollo, primero se puede poner un valor por defecto a los campos, `value="1"`, cuando se reciban en el `$_POST`, ya tendrás ese valor.

```html
      <li>Del colegio:
         <form action="" method="POST">
           <label>Lengua</label><input type="checkbox" name="iL" value="1"><br>
           <label>Matematica</label><input type="checkbox" name="iM" value="1"><br>
           <label>Ciencias naturales</label><input type="checkbox" name="iCN" value="1"><br>
           <label>Ciencias sociales</label><input type="checkbox" name="iCS" value="1"><br>
           <label>Ingles</label><input type="checkbox" name="ii" value="1"><br>
           <input type="submit">
         </form>
       </li>
```

Ahora en el PHP, tienes que verificar cuáles checkbox se han enviado, para ello puedes usar `isset()`, aunque PHP tiene una [forma abreviada](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) de hacerlo:

```php
$iL = $_POST["iL"] ?? '0'; 
$iM = $_POST["iM"] ?? '0';
$iCS = $_POST["iCS"] ?? '0';
$iCN = $_POST["iCN"] ?? '0';
$ii = $_POST["ii"] ?? '0';
```

Y listo, con eso ya no debe dar error al tratar de insertar:

```php
$m = "INSERT INTO `checkboxes` (`lengua`, `csociales`, `matematica`, `cnaturales`, `ingles`) 
VALUES ('$iL', '$iCS', '$iM', '$iCN', '$ii')";
mysqli_query($conexion, $m);
```

Por supuesto, no podía dejar pasar de que este desarrollo es susceptible a [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/80870), por lo que una vez aprendas lo necesario, también debes ir avanzando en temas de seguridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Se te agradece!